# Are Hunter's Mark and similar spells noticeable to the target?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Are Hunter's Mark / Hex / other spells like that noticeable to the target of the spell?

I've watched Critical Role, and it looks like the only thing the character needs to do is pass a sleight of hand check if they are visible to the target (but Hunter's Mark has a verbal component, not a somatic one?).

The basic question is: Can the target tell in any way if they are now marked, by way of seeing, hearing, or just feeling like, "Oh man, I feel magic on me." Would it make a difference if the target was a magic user, or a commoner, or a beast?

Comment: Matt Mercer has on occasion called for a sleight of hand check, this is always outside of a combat situation when an NPC is being marked to allow following or tracking. As the roll has never been failed (to my knowledge) my guess is that the DC is relatively low. In addition the characters that have been hunters marked tend to be NPC’s who have a level of arcane knowledge, lot Briarwod, a vampire, a seller of magical curiosities and potions. So for flavor Matt may be asking for the check to see if the target is aware of the magic, or he might just be making the player worried. Roll a dice, ok