# Can you tell if someone transfers Hunter's Mark or Hex after the original target is reduced to 0 HP?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, spell-components

The spells *[hunter's mark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark)* and *[hex](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hex)* both include this clause:

> If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to [mark/curse] a new creature.

Both of these spells have spellcasting components that would be observable to another creature when the spell is initially cast. If I want to mark or curse someone, anyone nearby will know.

If the original target is reduced to 0 HP, is it observable in any way should the caster choose to transfer their mark/curse to another creature? Or is this essentially untraceable after the initial casting?

Obviously for this question, I am ignoring a sorcerer's Subtle Spell metamagic. We can also assume that this is not from stealth; the caster is not trying to hide what they are doing, this is more about whether or not there is anything to hide beyond the initial casting.

---

Related:

- [Is a creature aware that a Hex or Hunter's Mark spell has been cast on it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64549/35259) (but related to the initial casting from stealth)
- [Are Hunter's Mark and similar spells noticeable to the target?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72443/35259) (duplicate of the above, still about the original casting)
- [Does moving the curse from the Hex spell to a new target have any spell components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72738/35259) (regarding if the transferring part requires components)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Only through *Detect Magic* or a similar spell/feature

As covered in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72738/60913), *Hex* does not require components when moved to a new creature. A creature cannot recognize that *Hex* has been moved by observing the spellcaster fulfilling the component requirements.

There are features, however, that allow creatures to detect magic, the most obvious example of which is the spell *Detect Magic*. A creature using this spell or benefitting from a similar effect would be able to perceive the magic of *Hex* on the new target.

Since *Hex* and *Hunter's Mark* use similar wordings to describe moving the effect to a new creature, *Hunter's Mark* would also be undetectable when moved, except through *Detect Magic* or a similar feature.